# What is the point of "cd ." in "cd . && npm install"?

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I'm using [express generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). After running the generator it outputs the following:

```
   install dependencies:
     $ cd . && npm install
```

What is the point of `cd .`?

Comment: `cd .` just means current directory, `&&` say do both . don't see much point of `cd .` where did you find the code.

Comment: @RiazLaskar ^^  description.

Comment: ya viewed the page first, don't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you ran this:

```
$ express
```

(or possibly `express .`)

In other words, you told `express-generator` to create a project in the current working directory. Alternatively, you could have provided a subdirectory name:

```
$ express foo
```

In that case, the commandline it generates makes a bit more sense:

```
install dependencies:
  $ cd foo && npm install
```

Comment: Totally makes sense. They probably didn't find it worthwhile to do an `if` condition to check for the working directory.